# Laravel increment table if null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with incrementing a specific row in my table. By default the row is set to NULL, so the increment is not working. 
So basically I want to tell my function to update the row if it's null and if not to increment it. This is my code:

```
$wday->week = $week;
    $wday->hours = $request->hours;
    $wday->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $wday->tasks()->associate($task);
    if ($wday->tasks('days_r') != NULL) {
        $wday->tasks()->increment('days_r', $request->hours);
    }else{
        $wday->tasks()->update(['days_r' => $request->hours]);
    }
    $wday->save();
```

I can't find why my IF is not working! Any solutions?

Comment: What is `$wday->tasks('days_r')` supposed to reference?   That wouldn't be how you access a property on a relationship.

Comment: What is `$wday`? Is it an object coming from the database or a new object?

Comment: $wday is a new object 
'days_r' is the row i'm trying to update. I use '$wday->task()' because I update a row in pivot table.

Comment: Ye I'm stupid... @Devon was right, it's not the proper way to access the property.

`if ($task->days_r != NULL) {

            $wday->tasks()->increment('days_r', $request->hours);

        }else{

            $wday->tasks()->update(['days_r' => $request->hours]);

        }`

Now it's working. Thanks!